# 4l2loopback: NOOBS Trouble

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, pyffmpeg

I have installed v4l2loopback on my NOOBS OS but it is not working.

I have checked if v4l2loopback is installed and it is. But when I type in `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2`, it says that it isn't found in the directory.

Here is the proof that it is installed:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
v4l2loopback-dkms is already the newest version (0.10.0-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  realpath
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback-dkms
modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback-dkms not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+
```

I am expecting to activate the v4l2loopback but I am receiving this error message below..

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=2
modprobe: FATAL: Module v4l2loopback not found in directory /lib/modules/4.19.58-v7+
```

Comment: I have the same problem on manjaro linux5.4.33-3-MANJARO if you ever solved it

Answer (score 0):

Simply reboot

If you did a kernel upgrade without rebooting, then the kernel that is actually running and the installed kernel are different. The running kernel looks in its version of the directory (which no longer exists) instead of the installed directory.